# Cesium CZML file for billboard with trailing line

Tags: cesium

I am looking for some tips on creating a CZML file that has uses a billboard to track a pedestrian walking over a terrain (and has a few custom properties for each time sample). About 18K samples. My naive assumption is to put this in one or more packets.

And then have a seperate id for a path that grows as trace of the path (with the head being the billboard). And this would be in a seperate packet,

and Both would have a epoch for the start and then sample properties for each time step

I.e. the epoch would be today at noon, and the sample properties would be 1 second intervals for each position of the pedestrian which would be duplicated for both the polyline and the billboard.

But is there a better way, and I assume someone has done a sandcastle with an example, right?

Answer (score 1):

I found an example that shows how one can do this more effectively than what I thought:

https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=CZML%20Path.html&label=